# How to create namespace XML using XSLT applying on other XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file that i will transform to another XML file:

```
<Report>
  <MessageDetails>
    <MessageGeneratedOn>2016-01-13T17:56:22</MessageGeneratedOn>
    <ReportingPeriod>2016-12-31</ReportingPeriod>
  </MessageDetails>
  <Reporting1>
    <OrganizationName>API Guernsey Limited</OrganizationName>
    <DistrictName>Windsor</DistrictName>
    <City>Corres</City>
  </Reporting1>
</Report>
```

I apply the following XSLT to transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Report">
    <FATCA_OECD version="1.1" schemaLocation="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1 FatcaXML_v1.1.xsd" >
      <xsl:element name ="ReportingPeriod">
        <xsl:value-of select="MessageDetails/ReportingPeriod"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name ="Timestamp">
        <xsl:value-of select="MessageDetails/MessageGeneratedOn"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <Reporting1>

        <xsl:element name ="Name">
          <xsl:value-of select="ReportingFI/Name"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <Address>
          <xsl:element name ="DistrictName">
            <xsl:value-of select="ReportingFI/Address2"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name ="City">
            <xsl:value-of select="ReportingFI/City"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </Address>
      </Reporting1>

    </FATCA_OECD>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This create the following XML:

```
<FATCA_OECD version="1.1" schemaLocation="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1 FatcaXML_v1.1.xsd">
  <MessageSpec>
    <ReportingPeriod>2016-12-31</ReportingPeriod>
    <XMLTimeStamp>2016-01-13T17:56:22</XMLTimeStamp>
  </MessageSpec>
  <FATCA>
    <Reporting1>
      <Address>
        <DistrictName></DistrictName>
        <City>Corres</City>
      </Address>
    </Reporting1>
    <ReportingGroup />
  </FATCA>
</FATCA_OECD>
```

But i need XML with namespace.How can i create XML with namespace like the following?:

```
<ftc:FATCA_OECD version="1.1" schemaLocation="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1 FatcaXML_v1.1.xsd">
  <ftc:MessageSpec>
    <sfa:ReportingPeriod>2016-12-31</sfa:ReportingPeriod>
    <sfa:XMLTimeStamp>2016-01-13T17:56:22</sfa:XMLTimeStamp>
  </ftc:MessageSpec>
  <ftc:FATCA>
    <ftc:Reporting1>
      <sfa:Address>
        <sfa:DistrictName></sfa:DistrictName>
        <sfa:City>Corres</sfa:City>
      </sfa:Address>
    </Reporting1>
      <ftc:ReportingGroup />
  </ftc:FATCA>

</ftc:FATCA_OECD>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your expected output is _still_ a document without a namespace, it only has prefixed names, but is lacking namespace _declarations_.

Comment: To clarify: your expected output is not well-formed XML and cannot be produced as a result of an XSL transformation. You cannot use a prefix without binding it  to a namespace (URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stylesheet, add an `xmlns:fatcav1="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1"` attribute to the `xsl:stylesheet` element, meaning you declare that any reference to the `fatcav1` prefix means that you are referencing the namespace with the URI `urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1`. Now for *all* the elements that you produce in your XSLT, prefix them with `fatcav1` (such as `<fatcav1:FATCA_OECD ...`), meaning that you are creating a `FATCA_OECD` element *in the namespace associated with the `fatcav1` prefix*. Make sure to add this prefix to *all elements*.

There are other ways to achieve the same goal, but this is a good way to make it very obvious to anybody looking at the XSLT code that you are creating XML elements from that specific namespace.
You can choose any prefix you like (such as `ftc` you have used in your example). What really matters is the namespace URI, and the element names. I usually try to make the prefixes a bit "speaking", so that a reader can better figure out what a namespace is about.

Comment: Hi dret, I am getting the expected output. Thanks very much for help.